# Using Google Admin SDK to get a location for devices

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I can use the Google admin api to get a list of all devices giving to users.
Is there any way to get the location information from the api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Apps Admin SDK - Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) only lets you perform administrative operations on users, groups, organization units, and devices in your account. This doesn't have the feature to give device locations.

You may opt to use [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/obtain-location?hl=en) to obtain the user's current location information. However, as mentioned in the documentation, location information that you can get depends on the location device your browser is using.

For more information, please also try going through these additional documentations:

- [Geolocation: Displaying User or Device Position on Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/geolocation)
- [The Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro)